# Где искать log файл в структуре bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

Вылезла ошибка 500. Пытаюсь освоить bitrix. Понял из форумов, что надо искать причину ошибки в логах. Но перерыл всю структуру - не понять, где он.

Comment: Смотрите логи хостинга/сервера. Какая ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно включить показ ошибок bitrix/www/bitrix/.settings.php

'debug' => true,

тоже самое с базой данных .

bitrix/www/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php

Также можно заменить  'log' => null на

```
'log' => 
      array (
        'settings' => 
        array (
          'file' => '/var/log/php/exceptions.log',
          'log_size' => 1000000,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Так, выставил дебаг в настройках. И что должно появиться?

Comment: будут ошибки показаны на сайте

Comment: Также может быть проблема с настройкой сервера) Apache или Nginx

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CUser::AuthActionsCleanUpAgent() in /home/u298387/fortuna-snack.ru/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/mysql/agent.php(159) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Ошибка в 159 строке?

Comment: Проблема или в коде или в базе с агентом попробуй сделать то что рекомендуют тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic37658/

Comment: Что там в строке 159??

Comment: просто закомментил строку и все заработало, доступ к админке появился. Но теперь сам сайт выдает ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Comment: Не, все супер!!! Спасибо